# Python Telegram Bot open URL/join another Telegram Group after pressing telegram.KeyoardButton

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

do someone know if there is a way to open a URL when someone write /start or some command.
I already tried with requests, but it hasnt worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect users to other groups/chats by providing them with an invite link or the username of the group/channel in the `@username` format. If you want that to happen on the press of a button, you can use `InlineKeyboardButton` by passing the invite link directly to the button, i.e. `InlineKeyboardButton(text='some_text', url='http://t.me/…')`. The URL will open (i.e. redirect the user to the target chat), when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks!
But is it possible to do it with normal KeyboardButton? ReplyKeyboardMarkup

Comment: No, those are just shortcuts for sending predefined text

Comment: @CallMeStag Hi, Can I force telegram bot to open url (invite link in this case) using telegram not phone browser? Unfortunately in android 12 and above links are opened by browser.